# Insert foreign key into database using dapper in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

I Want to insert into sql table with foreign key in c# using dapper, Here is my code. When I do it this way it gives me a conversion error.

```
public class LoanModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public CustomerModel CustomerID { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public InterestModel Interest { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

This is the method that fills the data gridview:

```
List<LoanModel> Loans = new List<LoanModel>();

public void FillCustomersDataGridview()
{
    try
    {
        DataAccess.ShowLoan(SearchCustomTextBox.Text.Trim());
        dataGridView1.DataSource = Loans;
    }
    catch (Exception ERE)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"An error occured: {ERE.Message}");
    }
}
```

This is the method that inserts the data into the database:

```
public static void GetLoan(int id, int customerID, int amount, int interest, DateTime loanDateDateTimePicker)
{
    using (IDbConnection Con = new SqlConnection(Helper.ConnectionString("DatabaseConnection")))
    {
        LoanModel Loan = new LoanModel { ID = id, CustomerID = customerID, Amount = amount, Interest = interest, Date = loanDateDateTimePicker };
        List<LoanModel> newLoan = new List<LoanModel>();
        newLoan.Add(Loan);
        Con.Execute("spGetLoan @ID, @CustomerID, @Amount, @Interest, @Date", newLoan);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you have pass list to insert data into the database time.

Your Query

```
List<LoanModel> newLoan = new List<LoanModel>();
                    newLoan.Add(Loan);
                    Con.Execute("spGetLoan @ID, @CustomerID, @Amount, @Interest, @Date", newLoan);
```

Please direct pass only model

```
Con.Execute("spGetLoan @ID, @CustomerID, @Amount, @Interest, @Date", Loan);
```

Comment: Ok I will try that, but the problem is with customer ID and InterestI. Since the data table the customerID is of type customerModel and Interest is of type Interest, when I pass the entry from the textboxes to them it gives me a conversion error

Comment: Please check datatype of the model and after check datatype of the stored procedure.

Comment: The error message has nothing to do with the stored procedure,the problem is when I assigned the method parameter to the model property, because the method parameter is of type int and the model property is of type customer for example.